# Relacionar 3 tablas para proyecto java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una duda en cuanto a ***mysql*** + ***java***, estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual necesito utilizar 3 tablas, y utilizar métodos para llamar datos en común, pero no sé como hacerlas de una forma en la cual las 3 se relacionen para hacer las consultas.

Ya que necesito una tabla cliente con datos de un cliente, una de estacionamiento y una boucher, es decir, registrar un cliente y agregar el estacionamiento en el cual aparco su auto, luego buscar con el RUT del cliente para listar todos los aparcamientos que realizo con su numero de ticket y monto, luego generar un boucher o boleta con los datos de los estacionamientos (nombre,numero de ticket y monto a pagar) y opción de envió del boucher que es un dato de clientes (metodo de envio),aqui tengo mas menos lo que pense,pero no se como unirlas ...

*este es el inicio con el nombre y todo eso

```html
create database clienteDB;

use clienteDB;
```

- Aqui van todos los datos del cliente

```html
create table clientes(
    id int auto_increment,
    nombre varchar(50),
    apellido varchar(50),
    correo varchar(50),
    formaPago varchar(50),
    formaBoleta varchar(50),
    telefono int(10),
    rut varchar(10),  
    primary key(id),
    unique(rut),
    unique(numeroTicket)
);
```

*aqui necesito la forma de que con el rut,rescatar los datos de cuantos registros ingreso el usuario al estacionamiento 1 o más

```html
create table estacionamientos(
    idEsta int auto_increment,
    nombreEstacionamiento varchar(50),
    numeroTicket int(5),
    precioEstacionamiento int(10), 
    primary key(idEsta),
    unique(numeroTicket)
);
```

*aqui necesito que aparte generar el boucher con su numero de boucher,muestre los datos del estacionamiento y la opcion de envio que pidio el cliente

```html
create table boucher(
    idBoucher int auto_increment,    
    numeroBoucher int(5),    
    primary key(idBoucher ),
    unique(numeroBoucher )
);
```

eso es mas o menos lo que tengo en mente,pero solo encontre formas de hacerlo con mysql admin y yo necesito crear el script con las tablas,espero que haya sido claro,muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: con MsqlWorbech puedes generar el script de tu base de datos ...

Comment: Tu pregunta no es del todo clara. Supongo que esos son los `CREATE TABLE` que tu ejecutas (no desde Java), para tener tus tablas creadas. Bien, a tus tablas le faltan las relaciones (cómo se relacionan las tablas entre sí y por qué columnas; qué debe ocurrir cuando un registro de una tabla relacionada es borrado o es actualizado)... eso es lo primero que te debe quedar claro. Segundo, para obtener lo que deseas, tendrás que consultar tus tablas mediante un `SELECT` que una mediante `JOIN` las diferentes tablas por las columnas relacionadas que hayas declarado. ¿Entiendes lo que te digo?